# How many iterations does Grover’s search need to find one out of $M$ marked items?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

How many iterations are needed in Grover’s quantum search for finding one out of M marked items in a database containing N items (for 1 < M < N/2)?

I would have thought we just reduce the size of the search space to M and then calculate the probability? But then does that mean the size of the overall database does not matter here?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1939/55

Answer (score 4):

R iterations where $(2R+1)\theta\approx\pi/2$ and $\sin\theta=\sqrt{M/N}$

Regarding your question, how do you “just reduce the size of the search space”?

Answer (score 0):

At the cost of over-simplifying:

For the second part of your question, Grover's search helps in marking the `M` items in the whole database. You're still searching a whole database of `N` items.

The beauty in this implementation is that when we measure, the probability of finding these `M` items is higher than all the other non-marked items in the database.