# Can I use Grover's algorithm for a function that has multiple arguments which satisfy it?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

Let's say we have a function $f(x)$, where $f(011) = 1$, and $f(111) = 1$.

Can I still use Grover's algorithm with this function, and receive the result of either $011$, or $111$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In fact, Grover's algorithm generally requires fewer iterations if more than one bitstring satisfies the search condition.

More precisely, suppose we wish to find one of $M$ $n$-bit strings that fulfill a condition encoded by $f$ and assume that $0<M \le \frac{N}{2}$ where $N=2^n$ is the number of all $n$-bit strings. The number $R$ of Grover iterations required is bounded by

$$
R \le \left\lceil\frac{\pi}4\sqrt\frac{N}{M}\right\rceil = O\left(\sqrt{\frac{N}{M}}\right),
$$

see inequality $(6.17)$ on page 254 in Nielsen & Chuang. (Note that the above only applies when $M \le \frac{N}{2}$, but we can extend the result to $M > \frac{N}{2}$ at the expense of adding a qubit because then the new $N'=2^{n+1}$ and $M \le N = \frac{N'}{2}$.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Grover's algorithm is often described in terms of looking for a single solution, but it is easily generalized to functions with multiple solutions, and numbers of solutions unknown beforehand.

Here is a couple of relevant SE questions:

- [What to do when the amount of solutions is not known before applying Grovers Algorithm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/what-to-do-when-the-amount-of-solutions-is-not-known-before-applying-grovers-alg)
- [Grover algorithm for more than one element](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/grover-algorithm-for-more-than-one-element)
- [How many iterations does Grover’s search need to find one out of $M$ marked items?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9063/how-many-iterations-does-grover-s-search-need-to-find-one-out-of-m-marked-item)